# Insert in string AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I need to insert string in another string in specific index.

```
var str1:String = "A";

var str2:String = "LoremIpsum";
```

I need `str2` to be `"LoremAIpsum"`, insert `str1` in index 5 in `str2`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strings are immutable in AS3. So you cannot insert in a string. You need to get the substrings and create a new string.

```
var str1:String = "A";
var str2:String = "LoremIpsum";
var index:int = 5;
var str3:String = str2.slice(0, index) + str1 + str2.slice(index);
trace(str3);
```